# How to import Azure blob file into Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, clr, bulk-import

Is there a way to import Blob files into sql server 2008 other than using CLR ?

The file size is around 300MB so CLR isn't efficient enough. Is there a possibility to use `BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET` in 2008 server?

Example in Sql Server 2017 we can do this

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureDevBlobImportCred
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'st=2018-12-05T.....'

go

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureDevBlobImportExternalSrc
WITH  (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net', -- storage account URL
    CREDENTIAL = AzureDevBlobImportCred -- External Data Source
);
```

then we can use the external data source in bulk import

```
BULK INSERT #Mytemptable 
FROM 'filename'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureDevBlobImportExternalSrc'
);
```

So do we have something like above to import blob files in Sql Server 2008 ?

Comment: @LeonYue done, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the document:[BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#see-also).

SQL Server 2008 supports `BULK INSERT`: starting with 2008.
[image]
 So you can use `BULK INSERT` in SQL Server 2008.

But if you data_file is in Azure blob storage, your SQL Server version must begin with  SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CTP1.1. The same with `OPENROWSET`.
[image]

It means that you could not import Blob files into SQL Server 2008 with `BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET`.

Hope this helps.